# Create rails SUM query object

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In DB there ara many accounts, every account has lots of transactions with price attribute. It's needed to count account balance by summarize all transaction prices.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end
end
```

Account model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, dependent: :destroy
  includes :transactions

  def balance
    transactions.sum(:price) || 0
  end

  def balance_ruby_sum
    sum = 0
    transactions.each { |t| sum+= t.price }
    sum
  end
end
```

Transaction model:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

account index.html.erb:

```
<table>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>balance</th>
    <% @accounts.each do |acc| %>
        <td><%= acc.name %></td>
        <td><%= acc.balance %></td>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

In index view I have account's name and its balance.
It's needed to fire N+1 queries to DB to do this and I want to avoid N+1 problem.
I tried to use `balance_ruby_sum` action instead of `balance` action (only 2 queries are needed), but it's not a good solution (performance issue).

I don't want to retrieve all full transaction, only their sum of prices. Is it possible to count balance by sum prices using SQL and do only 2 queries?

I found an [article](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) there in 4 item described how to use a query object. But I don't understand how to create a one in my case.

Comment: Your `balance` method is correct. How do you call it that it causes N+1?

Comment: For ex. if I have 10 accounts I need to fire 11 queries to get accounts and their balances and only 2 queries if I use `balance_ruby_sum`. Is it possible to get balance by summarize prices in 2 queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to play with `select` like this and you should have what you want in a single query.

```
@accounts = Account.all.joins(:transactions).
  select("accounts.*, SUM(transactions.price) AS balance").
  group("accounts.id")
```

The only problem with this query is that you will only get the accounts that actually have transactions. Those without transactions will be left out.

**What's happening**

The first part `Account.all.joins(:transactions)` joins the `accounts` and `transactions` table together. `ActiveRecord` is clever enough to know that we're using `account_id` on the transactions to join the tables.

Next, what we want on this join table is the account information, but we'd like an "extra field" that is the sum of all that accounts transactions prices. We basically want:

```
+-------------+-----+-----+---------+
|  account id | ... | ... | balance |
+-------------+-----+-----+---------+
```

That's why we need the `select` statement `select("accounts.*, SUM(transactions.price) AS balance")`. We're telling `ActiveRecord` to give us, in this join table, all the account attributes and also to build a special one, `balance`, that is the sum of all transaction prices associated to this account.

Finally, we need to give `ActiveRecord` a clue on how to organize the results and we tell it to group the records by account id. Which in our case means one account per line.

**balance_ruby_sum**

If you want to keep your `balance_ruby_sum` method, you might wanna consider using `inject` like this:

```
def balance_ruby_sum
  transactions.inject(0) { |sum, t| sum + t.price }
end
```

You won't gain performance but it's more rubyesque :)

**Edit return 0 when no transaction as requested in comments:**

To make sure we get one line per Account even if there is no transaction attached. We need to force a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

Now `SUM`, when there is no transaction, will return `NULL` as balance and we want it to return 0. The way to return 0 when there are no transactions is to use the `COALESCE` keyword around `SUM`. `COALESCE` is used to return a default value in case the first parameter is `NULL`. Your request now looks like this:

```
@accounts = Account.all.
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions ON accounts.id = transactions.account_id").
  select("accounts.*, COALESCE(SUM(transactions.price), 0) as balance").
  group("accounts.id")
```

You can read more about `INNER JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN` here:
[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's that I need. Btw: what could you suggest if I need balance (0 or "no transactions") for accounts which don't have transactions? Fire a separate query? Could I use eager_load(:transactions) or not? I'm not sure that my variant to use default "no transactions" for those accounts is pretty enough.

Comment: Edited my answer with a possible one query solution to return 0 when no transactions. Please try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only issue is that in case using 'LEFT JOIN' there is no SQL select optimization by ref. When I do `explain` for query, I see that it scans all rows in account and transaction tables.

Comment: Maybe you can optimise that with the right index. Make sure there is an index on transactions.account_id. That should do the trick. You should already have one on accounts.id